# About typescript define an object who has not contain a field the type defined

Tags: typescript

Assume I have an interface `Book`:

```
interface Book {
    id: number
    info: {
        name: string,
    }
}
```

Now I define a list named `bookList`:

```
const bookList: Book[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        info: {
            name: 'bookA',
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2
    }
]
```

Absolutely I will get an error like this:

```
Property 'info' is missing in type '{ id: number; }' but required in type 'Book'.
```

Then I add a `?` to the `Book` like this:

```
interface Book {
    id: number
    info?: {
        name: string,
    }
}
```

The error will gone.

**But** when I get name like below:

```
console.log('book name', bookList[0].info.name)
```

Here comes another error:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Of cause I can do like this: `bookList[0].info!.name` or `bookList[0].info?.name`
But I have multiple code like `bookList[0].info.name`, I don't want to add ! or ? everywhere.

Could someone please kindly suggest me how to solve this?

Here is the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0GtkG8BQyRywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbSHGgzqUHFdVy0SUBnMFFABzADTMiAX3yz8CdCCHJ6mLABlgQyhmwBtALrIAvMn1S8lrmUoBGSdxYg2Ha0559KAcjXYAgt6OHrJc0sFEnB62yABMlrKG+ApKAugANhAAdOnoogAUvuqeEEGq6lpC+gAMhlms6FkgvBAAlEA)

Comment: "But I have multiple code like `bookList[0].info.name`".  Please show that in your [mre] so we can advise.

Answer (score 1):

That's right becase info property is possibly undefiend
you can have question mark by using that, like this :

```
console.log('book name', bookList[0].info?.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to put `!` after `info`. `console.log('book name', bookList[0].info!.name)`

Note: `!` operator tells the compiler to ignore the possibility of it being undefined.

Comment: I know this way, but I have multiple code like `bookList[0].info.name`, I don't want to add ! everywhere, is there another way?

Comment: otherwise, how typescript must understand if info is defiend ? @lv_

Comment: Aha, I see. Well, I do not know if it is helpful, but I would probably just define a function something like following: getName(i: index) { return bookList[i].info!.name } and use it instead.

Comment: @UrskaKrivc Thanks, but this seems will cause the same error.

Comment: Oh, it is working for me. But instead of 'index', I should put 'number' in my previous comment.

Comment: @UrskaKrivc Yes it worked, I just have some misspell. Thanks!